# Background is getting blurred when i add hdri or exr files in Blender 2.8

Tags: animation, hdri

I am trying to animate a drone in Shading Mode and also imported hdri images in World mode.

But,most of the time i see everything blurred in the background even with the original hdri images from hdrimap and hdri haven and also sometimes i convert mp4 to hdri or exr ,but in all cases background is blurred. 
Please help ,also attaching screenshot.

[image]

Comment: Your camera. Is your camera set to have depth of field?